# Logged in, sending a message does NOT work, and calling DOES work after reinstall

Tags: skype

NOTHING has changed since I tried UN-installing and RE-installing Skype from scratch of the Android 5.0 Note 3.  Except NOW, the CONTACTS are only showing from one contact, which is really odd.  Seems NO contacts or ALL contacts should have shown up.  When I tired to log in with my account, using the same app, ALL my contacts showed up immediately.

- All VOICE calls work flawlessly, TO or FROM.
- Any MESSAGES fail, TO or FROM.
- When trying to send a message from the phone, it never gets
  past the circle and "sending" indicator.

Yesterday, I noticed that my wife's android Skype didn't send or receive the messages I sent or should have received.  Tried calling the phone using Skype, that did work.  Also tried sending and receiving a message to/from her phone, WHILE on the call.  Messages never worked at all.

Separately, I tried this while logged into BOTH a web based Skype UI, AND the Windows (desktop) installed Skype.  Messages from me or to me worked, as long as they didn't originate or should have been received on the phone.

The problem must not be her account, nor any settings, nor any interference from another logged in Skype session on any other device.  Although I haven't tried logging into her account on my phone, I doubt if there will be a problem.  The problem is obviously isolated to JUST her phone.  I DID try to log into MY account on her phone, but all my contacts and messages showed up, and sending and receiving worked flawlessly on her phone.

It appears that there must be TWO modules -- with separate logins...

- Voice, which logs in and works.
- Messages, which doesn't, since it is not logged in, but only failed to log in with HER account.